# @Html.DisplayFor — Adding extra plain text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have two values that I want to show: with brackets around 'Description'

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)           
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
```

But instead of writing it like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
(
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
)
```

I'd like to clean it up and write it like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name + "(" + item.Description + ")"))
```

*Similar to PHP Echo*

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to display the `Description` surrounded by brackets only when `Description` is not empty, so add a new property in your model as follows

```
public string NameAndDescription
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Description))
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Name + " (" + this.Description + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

then display the new property in your view like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameAndDescription)
```

Comment: The only 'kind of' problem is that, whenever a task does not have a description, it would crash. My initial way would show the brackets. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does it crash exactly?

Comment: Well, it doesn't crash, after all.. I assumed it would. (my bad). However, it does still show the brackets even when it doesn't have a description.

Comment: See the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! It works exactly how I want it.